# Switch inside Channel:Categories?

Tags: categories, switch

I would like to insert a clearfix div after every third category listing. I have used this method successfully when outputting from `{exp:channel:entries}` tag pairs, but it appears that the `{switch}` variable is not available for `{exp:channel:categories}` tag pairs.

Is there another way to accomplish this (perhaps with CSS, jQuery, or another EE function I'm unaware of)?

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="Projects" style="linear" show_empty="no" dynamic="no" disable="member_data|pagination"}
<div class="column one-third">
    <div class="pic">
        <a href="{path='our-work/list'}">
        {if category_image}{exp:ce_img:single src="{category_image}" crop="yes" width="420" height="290" filter="auto_sharpen"}
        {if:else}<img src="{lv_shortcuts_project_image_none}" alt=""/>{/if}
        <div class="img_overlay"></div></a>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="{path='our-work/list'}">{category_name}</a></h3>
    <p>{category_description}</p>
</div>
{switch='||<div class="clearfix"></div>'} <!-- DOES NOT WORK -->
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the exact number of categories that will be displayed? You may be able to use a conditional with the {count} variable.

Comment: I don't know exactly how many categories there will be. The client will decide that.

Comment: @mjr, Thanks for the idea. I did get it working with `{if count == "3" OR count == "6"}<div class="clearfix"></div>{/if}` for now. It is unlikely they will ever have more than 8 categories. Do you want to post your idea as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: will do, glad it worked for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the exact number of categories that will be displayed, you can use conditionals in combination with the {count} variable.

Answer (score 5):

The [**GWcode Alternate addon**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gwcode-alternate) will accomplish what you need.

> This simple plugin for ExpressionEngine 1 and 2 lets you rotate
>   through any number of values to create alternations, for CSS classes
>   for example.
>
> You can use this plugin to rotate through any number of values,
>   similar to the switch variable in the {exp:channel:entries} tag for
>   example.
>
> The most straightforward use for this would be to alternate CSS
>   classes.

**Code example**

```
<ul>
    {exp:channel:categories channel="example" style="linear"}
        {exp:gwcode_alternate count="{count}" alternate="one|two|three"}<li class="{alternate_value}">{alternate_value}: {category_name}</li>{/exp:gwcode_alternate}
    {/exp:channel:categories}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

I see this has already been answered, but there is a jQuery option that might be better for you. At least it won't matter how many categories there are:

```
$('.selector:nth-child(3n)').after($('<div />').addClass('clearfix'));
```

This will select every 3rd element that matches `.selector` and insert `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after it.